# How to fetch data using link in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typescript, next.js

My data is stored in Mongo Atlas. I can fetch the data (posts) but when I click on the post, it doesn't provide me with the data of that ID. I have created a pages/posts page. I am only able to view the ID of the post due to the code below which is in postlist.tsx and is only passing the id to the next page via its url. I want to be able to view the title and body of the post associated with that particular ID as well:

This is my **blogs.tsx**

```
    interface PostState{
        posts: Post[];
    }

    export default class PostList extends React.Component <{},PostState> {
            state = {
                posts: []
            };

            componentDidMount = () => {
                this.getBlogPost();
            };

            getBlogPost = () => {

                axios
                    .get('/api')
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        const reverseData = new Array;
                        for (let datetime = data.length - 1; datetime >= 0; datetime--) {
                            reverseData.push(data[datetime]);
                        }
                        this.setState({posts: reverseData})
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        alert('Error: there was an error processing your request')
                    })
            }

            displayBlogPost = (posts : Post[]) => {
                const currentDateTime = new Date();
                if (!posts.length) 
                    return null;

                return posts.map((post, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <Card>
                        <Title> 

                            <Link href={`/post?id=${post._id}`} as= . 
       {`/post/${post._id}`}></Title>
                        {/* <p>{post.date}</p>
                        <p>{post.name}</p> */}

                        <FullName>{`${post.name} | 
       ${dateToString(currentDateTime)}`}</FullName>
                        <Line />
                        <Question >{post.body}</Question>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                ));
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Container>
                        <Headers/>
                        <div className="blog">
                            {this.displayBlogPost(this.state.posts)}
                        </div>                   
                        </Container>
                    </div>

                );
            }

    }
```

Comment: Kind of pointless to use nextjs if most of your component is rendered on the client after an xhr. Maybe getInitialProps from nextjs can help you out here.

Comment: What changes could I make to the code in order to achieve this? @HMR

Comment: I checked the getInitialProp however it is only accepting https fetch. What changes could I make to the code in order to get the posts body, title as per their ID? @HMR

Comment: You can start by actually rendering the PostsLists component anywhere.

Comment: I didn't get you. @HMR. I am able to render my postlist (blogs) .. I want that when someone clicks on the title of my blog, it  goes to a new page and displays the title and body according to its ID

Comment: In the code you posted in your question at no point are you rendering PostsList

Comment: return posts.map((post, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <Card>
                    <Title> 

                        <Link href={`/post?_id=${post._id} ` }
                        ><a>{post.title}</a></Link></Title>
                    {/* <p>{post.date}</p>
                    <p>{post.name}</p> */}

                    <FullName>{`${post.name} | ${dateToString(currentDateTime)}`}</FullName>
                    <Line />
                    <Question >{post.body}</Question>
                    </Card>
                </div>

Comment: Lets move on to the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209331/discussion-between-rebel-and-hmr).

Comment: hey I am now able to render 22 localhost:8080/post?id=22  @HMR

Comment: The best you can do @Rebel is to go through the [nextjs tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started), specially the topic on dynamic pages and fetching data.

Comment: I did, thats how I could reach till this much @ItaloAyres

Answer (score 0):

First you should create the Post [route](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/clean-urls-with-dynamic-routing/dynamic-routing)

pages/post/index.js

```
import React from 'react'

class Post extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
    return { query };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>id: {this.props.query.id}</div>
  }
}

export default Post
```

Then create pages/post/[id].js

```
import Post from './index'
export default Post
```

Now when you open `localhost:port/post/22` or `localhost:port/post?id=22` it should show you the number 22.

To link to a post from another page you can make the following link:

```
<Link href={`/post?id=${id}`} as={`/post/${id}`}>
  <a>{title}</a>
</Link>
```

If that still doesn't work then please show us the code (on github).

If it works then now you can pass an id to post page so you only need to fetch the post. You can do that in `getInitialProps`

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps({query}) {
    const post = await axios.get(url, { // make sure the url is full url, no relative urls
      params: {
        id: query.id
      }
    })
    return { post: post.data }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>
        post:{' '}
        {JSON.stringify(this.props.post, undefined, 2)}
      </pre>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: All the steps work fine besides the last step, the code where I have to paste the 
URL, I have pasted:
http://localhost:8080/api in the url section like  const post = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api' . This seems to render all my posts instead of rendering the title and body of that particular post

Comment: @Rebel ok, so now you can try this: `If that still doesn't work then please show us the code (on github).` without it it is just anyone's guess what else is wrong with the code.

Comment: I have added all my 3 files in the code above (updated code). There are literally no more files than these 3

Comment: So even if I upload the code, it will just be with these 3 files whose code I have pasted above. @HMR . But I could do all the steps. Just the last file seems to be having issue

Comment: @Rebel Here is a [working example](https://github.com/harm-meijer/nextjs-example)

Comment: @Rebel You are not doing anything with the post._id in your api: `server.get('/api', (req, res) => {` I would recommend using the example and put your mongodb logic in the pages/api/data.js file. Just add a getPosts and getPost function that is called from pages/api/posts/index.js and pages/api/post/index.js